# Why does classList return an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why I get an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
console.log(slid[numberArray].classList) - working, but
slid[numberArray].classList.add('active') - not working
I know that this is not a good code, but I'm still learning and I want to make a slider myself

```js
const slid = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slid')];
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrows-slider .arrow');

slid.forEach(s => {
    if( s.classList.contains('active') == false){
         s.style.opacity = '0';
    }
 });

arrows.forEach( arrow =>{
    arrow.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(this.classList.contains('arrows-right')){
            slid.forEach(s => {
                if( s.classList.contains('active')){
                    s.classList.remove('active');
                    let numberArray = slid.indexOf(s);
                    numberArray ++;
                    slid[numberArray].classList.add('active');
                    console.log(slid[numberArray].classList);
                }
             });
        }else if( this.classList.contains('arrows-left')){

        }

    });
});
```

```css
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/mirrored_squares.png');
    height: 100vh;
}

.slid {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

.img-slid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 35%;
    height: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.engine {
    background-image: url("../img/silnik.jpg");
}

.exhaust {
    background-image: url("../img/wydech.jpg");
}



.slid-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 11%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 8rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;

}

.number-slaid {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8%;
    right: 8%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
}

/* .arrows-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.line-arrow {
    width: 2px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
}

.top-line {
    transform: rotate(48deg) translateY(25%);
}

.bottom-line {
    transform: rotate(-48deg) translateY(-25%);
} */

.arrows-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.arrows-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}

.arrow {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slid slid1 active">
    <div class="engine img-slid"> </div>
    <p class="slid-text">engine</p>
    <p class="number-slaid">01</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slid slid2 ">
    <div class="exhaust img-slid"></div>
    <p class="slid-text">exhaust</p>
    <p class="number-slaid">02</p>
  </div>


  <div class="arrows-slider">
    <div class="arrows-left arrow"></div>
    <div class="arrows-right arrow"></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: What do you think happens when `s` is the last slider? What will `slid[numberArray]` be?

Comment: @SuperStormer I wanted add  " if(numberArray > slid.length-1) numberArray = 0; ", but that doesn't work either

Comment: @karamba: Where did you add that?  In what specific way did it "not work"?  Keep in mind that you're observing a very specific problem in a very specific part of the code.  When you use your browser's script debugger to step through the code, observe how each operation changes the values of the variables.  When you debug that specific attempt to solve the problem, what specific behavior do you observe in these operations and how does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's often a bad idea to use `Array.forEach()` in your scenario because it will go through the entire list even if your work was completed on the first element. So I highly suggest you use a loop you can break. Because After setting the next `element.classList.active`, there's no need for the list to continue.

Your Second Mistake was as David explained, not resetting back to position `0` when the last element of the list is reached.

Here's a working example. I've incorporated both `arrows-right` and `arrows-left` event behavior in one code.

```js
const slid = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slid')];
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.arrows-slider .arrow');

arrows.forEach( arrow =>
{
    arrow.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent)
    {
      var target = clickEvent.currentTarget;
        for(let i = 0; i < slid.length; i++)
        {
            if( slid[i].classList.contains('active'))
            {
                slid[i].classList.remove('active'); 
                let numberArray;
                
                if(target.classList.contains("arrows-right")) 
                {
                  numberArray = 0;
                  i++;  
                } else 
                {
                  numberArray = slid.length - 1;
                  i--;  
                } 
                
                if(slid[i] === undefined)
                  slid[numberArray].classList.add('active');
                else
                  slid[i].classList.add('active');
                  
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/mirrored_squares.png');
    height: 100vh;
}

.slid {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

.slid.active {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}

.img-slid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 35%;
    height: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.engine {
    background-image: url("../img/silnik.jpg");
}

.exhaust {
    background-image: url("../img/wydech.jpg");
}



.slid-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 11%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 8rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: green;
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;

}

.number-slaid {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8%;
    right: 8%;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
}

/* .arrows-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.line-arrow {
    width: 2px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
}

.top-line {
    transform: rotate(48deg) translateY(25%);
}

.bottom-line {
    transform: rotate(-48deg) translateY(-25%);
} */

.arrows-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.arrows-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-135deg);
}

.arrow {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slid slid1 active">
    <div class="engine img-slid"> </div>
    <p class="slid-text">engine</p>
    <p class="number-slaid">01</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slid slid2 ">
    <div class="exhaust img-slid"></div>
    <p class="slid-text">exhaust</p>
    <p class="number-slaid">02</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slid slid3 ">
    <div class="smoke img-slid"></div>
    <p class="slid-text">smoke</p>
    <p class="number-slaid">03</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="arrows-slider">
    <div class="arrows-left arrow"></div>
    <div class="arrows-right arrow"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over your `slid` array, you define `s` as each element in that array:

```
slid.forEach(s => {
```

You then define `numberArray` as the index of that element in that array:

```
let numberArray = slid.indexOf(s);
```

Then you increment `numberArray`:

```
numberArray ++;
```

And then access the element at that new index:

```
slid[numberArray].classList.add('active');
```

So what will happen when `s` is the last element of the array?  `numberArray` will be the index of that element, which you then increment to the index of the element *after the last element*.  No such element exists, so at that time `slid[numberArray]` is `undefined`.

How do you want to handle it when you've reached the end of the array?  However you want to handle it, that's where you'd implement that logic.

For example, if you want to start over at the beginning of the array when reaching the last element, you'd check if you're at the end of the array and reset to `0`:

```
let numberArray = slid.indexOf(s);
numberArray ++;
if (numberArray >= slid.length) {
  numberArray = 0;
}
slid[numberArray].classList.add('active');
```

Comment: this still won't make it work. This `numberArray ++;` set's the next element on the list as `active`, meaning when `Array.forEach()` goes to that element, it will process again because it will find it active, and it will keep recursing. Have you tried using what you suggested on a snippet? Because that's where I started before my answer below.

Comment: @MosiaThabo: I did try using this, yes.  It doesn’t “keep recursing” because there’s no recursion and because that’s not how loops work.  But I do certainly agree that just correcting this one error probably won’t “make it work” in the sense that the overall slider implementation likely still needs work.  And perhaps this loop isn’t needed at all and there’s a better approach.  Much of that work isn’t really in scope here.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain in detail. The above code(with your suggestion) will pass `active` to the next element in the loop. now when that next element runs, it will do the same... until it reaches the last element... and then it will return the `active` class back to the first element... In practice, with your suggested code applied, the first element will keep showing... it won't change. I've done this, so I know what I'm talking about. But I doubt if you have tried applying what you suggested above.

Comment: How about you copy the snippet from the question, paste it in your answer and apply your code and see what I'm talking about?

Comment: @MosiaThabo: I don’t doubt it.  My point is just that correcting the *error* and correcting the *overall logic of the application* are two very different things.  I didn’t address the entirety of the latter, and make no pretense otherwise.  If your answer does, that’s great!  That’s all the more help for the OP and future readers.  I’ve (perhaps implicitly) left the overall application logic as an exercise for the OP as part of their learning and practice.

Comment: Here's a Fiddle @David, with the suggested code. https://jsfiddle.net/mosiaonline/0ft9v6uw/2/

Comment: Fair Enough... ArrayBounds was the first culprit to that exception.. Overall, his approach just isn't going to work because of the near recursive behavior as I explained earlier. Shot!!